# Why use database migrations instead of a version controlled schema

Tags: orm, migration

Migrations are undoubtedly better than just firing up phpMyAdmin and changing the schema willy-nilly (as I did during my php days), but after using them for awhile, I think they're fatally flawed.

**Version control is a solved problem.** The main function of migrations is to keep a history of changes to your database. But storing a different file for each change is a clumsy way to track them. You don't create a new version of `post.rb` (or a file representing the delta) when you want to add a new *virtual* attribute -- why should you create a new migration when you want to add a new non-virtual attribute?

Put another way, just as you check `post.rb` into version control, why not check schema.rb into version control and make the changes to the file directly?

This is functionally the same as keeping a file for each delta, but it's much easier to work with. My mental model is "I want table X to have such and such columns (or really, I want model X to have such and such properties)" -- why should you have to infer from this how to get there from the existing schema; just open up `schema.rb` and give table X the right columns!

But even the idea that classes wrap tables is an implementation detail! Why can't I just open up `post.rb` and say:

```
 Class Post
    t.string :title
    t.text :body
 end
```

If you went with a model like this, you'd have to make a decision about what to do with existing data. But even then, migrations are overkill -- when you migrate data, you're going to lose fidelity when you use a migration's `down` method.

Anyway, my question is, **even if you can't think of a better way, aren't migrations kind of gross?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> why not check schema.rb into version control and make the changes to the file directly?

Because the database itself is not in sync with version control.

For instance, you could be using the head of the source tree.  But you're connecting to a database that was defined as some past version, not the version you have checked out.  The  migrations allow you to upgrade or downgrade the database schema from any version and to any version, incrementally.

But to answer your last question, yes, migrations are kind of gross.  They implement a redundant revision control system on top of another revision control system.  However, neither of these revision control systems is really in sync with the database.

Answer (score 9):

Just to paraphrase what others have said:  migrations allow you to protect the **data** as your schema evolves.  The notion of maintaining a single `schema.rb` file is attractive only until your app goes into production.  Thereafter, you'll need a way to *migrate* your existing users' data as your schema changes.

Comment: I assume you think you would have to re-create all the database/tables when updating database from "git" VCS, and preserve the data. I am not sure, there could be a tool for database migration, that would find out based on git timestamps, what to add, and from git commits aggregation you could find out exactly from commit to commit from date to date what exactly was added. Though the system might not be so intelligent to know what/how to revert migrate down, and would not be capable doint it so per migrate item. As some items you cannot revert while some other you might wish to.

Answer (score 6):

There are also data-related issues that are important to consider, which migrations solve.

Say an old version of my schema has a `feet` and `inches` column. For efficiency purposes, I want to combine that into just an `inches` column to make sorting and searching easier.

My migration can combine all of the feet and inches data into the inches column (feet * 12 + inches) while it's updating the database (i.e. just before it removes the `feet` column)

Obviously this being in a migration makes it automatically work when you later apply the changes to your production database.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, they're annoying and inadequate but quite possibly the best option we have available to us at present. Quite a few smart people have spent quite a lot of time working on the problem and this, so far, is about the best they've been able to come up with. After about 20 years of mostly hand-coding database version updates, I came very rapidly to appreciate migrations as a major improvement when I found ActiveRecord.

As you say, version control is a solved problem. Up to a point I'd agree: it's very solved for text files in particular, less so for other file types and not really very much at all for resources such as databases.

How do migrations look if you view them as version control deltas for databases? They're the sum of the deltas you have to apply to get a schema from one version to another. I'm not aware that even git, for all its super-powerfulness, can take two schema files and generate the necessary DDL to do that.

As far as declaring table content in the model, I believe that's what DataMapper does (no personal experience). I think there may be some DDL inference capabilities there as well.

"even if you can't think of a better way, aren't migrations kind of gross?"

Yes. But they're less gross than anything else we have. Do please let us know when you've completed the non-gross alternative.

Comment: good point, only some datamappers like doctrine are capable of it, as far as i know, yet you might want some DML statements of adding data, you might wish to be able to revert some changes and some not, plus even when systems like data mappers are capable to find out ddl changes from the schema definition. Only change I could see having all migrations in a single file = not that much difference, and finding out changes by git, but they could not be working, git allows single char changes. Plus like @Gareth mentioned eg. merging two columns.

Comment: Plus such a sql file would have to be executed by the git change order. Not necessarily by the arbitrary order defined in a sql file. And it would be less transparent. DML insert statements would have to be listed, also DDL remove column if they would not be automatically recognized, but some DDL like merging two columns would have to be listed as well, as it is (probably) not possible to recognize such a operation from a table definition. So it would not be transparent compared to migrations system we are used to, at all.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose given "even if you can't think of a better way", then yes, in the grand scheme of things, migrations are kind of gross.  So are Ruby, Rails, ORMs, SQL, web apps, ...

Migrations have the (not insignificant) advantage that they exist.  Gross-but-exists tends to win out over Pleasant-but-nonexistent.  I'm sure there probably are pleasant and nonexistent ways to migrate your data, but I'm not sure what that means.  :-)

Comment: Like the Winston Churchill quote about Democracy: it's the worst solution, except for all other solutions that have been tried.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to take a wild guess here and say that you're probably working all by yourself. In a group development project the power of each individual to take responsibility for just his/her changes to the database required for the code that developer is writing is much much more important.

The alternative is that larger groups of programmers (e.g. 10-15 Java developers where I work) end up relying on a couple of dedicated full time database administrators to do that along with their other maintenance, optimization, etc. duties.